# SQLAlchemy not closing sessions with ORM?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, bottle

I have a week end project with [Bottle.py](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) (0.10.11) and [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/)(0.7.9) using MySQL as a backend.

I had a lot of "MySQL server has gone away" and drilled it down to the fact that some sessions would be left opened during the night while I was not using my program.

Now I can see where the MySQL session is left open but I don't know how I should proceed.

This is what I have in my router page web.py

```
[...]
db = create_engine('mysql://USER:PASSWORD@DATABASE', poolclass=NullPool)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=db))

@route("/")
    links = session.query(Link)

    session.close()
    return bottle.template("index", links=links)
```

in my view index.tpl

```
[...]
%for link in links:
    <div class="link">
        <a class="link" href="{{link.url}}">{{link.title}}</a> 
        %for tag in link.tags:
            <a href="/tag/{{tag.text}}" class="tag">{{tag.text}}</a>
        %end
        <a href="/edit/{{link.id}}">edit</a>
    </div>
%end
[...]
```

If I use `session.query(Link).all()` instead of `session.query(Link)` the MySQL sessions are closed properly, but I can't benefit from the ORM factor.

How can I close all session ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you say `q = session.query(Link)`, that's a `Query` object that isn't executed yet.  You say `session.close()` fine, but then that `Query` object gets passed to your template and you iterate through it, which opens a new transaction on that `Session` to emit the SQL.

in this case you'd want to either stick with calling `all()` before closing the `Session`, or more flexibly just leave the `Session` open until the template is finished rendering.  Then the template can refer to lazy-loaded attributes as well.

Comment: Yes thanks, I think that's exactly what's happening. If I call `all()` I get this error `Parent instance <Link at 0x7f3c7f8270d0> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'tags' cannot proceed`. Where can I close the session after the template rendering ?

Comment: Ok I solved it, either add `.options(subqueryload('tags')).all()` to the `session.query(Link)` or add the lazy loading to the relationship definition `relationship("Tag", lazy='joined')` and call `session.query(Link).all()`